# Accesing blocks from the server via FTP

Tags: blocks, wsod

So I created a custom block and put the block on every page but unfortunately the block causes a white screen... I can't login to change the block because the block is on every page, as I mentioned. 
Is it possible using an FTP program to access blocks via the server and delete/change them?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, blocks are stored in the Database, not in your web directory. Therefore, FTP is useless here.

If the custom block was created using a custom module, simply disable the module.

If the custom block was created using the Drupal User Interface, you can disable your custom block by changing the status from 1 to 0 or edit the block body by login in into your Database using [PHPMyAdmin](http://i1-scripts.softpedia-static.com/screenshots/PHPMyAdmin_2.png) and finding the correct block table.

Comment: _FTP is useless here_ Have to take issue with that, it's simply not true. You can write a script which fixes the problem, then use FTP to upload it somewhere it can be executed. Might not be what the OP originally meant, but it's definitely a valid option, making FTP decidedly useful in this situation

Comment: I managed to fix it from switching off some the PHP code in the template.php file temporally which didn't render the block, so I was then able to login correctly, disable the block from admin and then switch the PHP back on again...  So technically I could fix it via FTP. The answer given would too it seems, so I appreciate that. Also, not sure why my question was down voted, surely it's a valid question?